# How does a skater moves by pushing sideways?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Take a look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmMf91AVUXc or take a look at the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the skater pushes almost perpendicular to the direction of movement but is able to maintain speed and accelerate.
Would you help me to understand why this works?

Comment: The key is that it's "almost" perpendicular. If you do a diagram of the forces, you'll see there's a force component that's actually propelling the skater forward.

Comment: I suspect you have not gone roller skating before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing sideways provides a reactionary force which pushing backwards cannot provide. As you can see, the skater is not pushing *completely* perpendicular to his motion. There is a component of the reactionary normal force along the direction of his motion, and this force provides the thrust.

Comment: Pushing backward works just fine (though, it's kind of awkward to do it).  Pushing in any direction will move the skater so long as the blade of the skate does not line up with the direction of the push.